# Change date format for a specific IDs

Tags: mysql, datetime, format

I have a problem in my date format i have entered a record with format yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii and other records with dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii and i wan to change all date format to dd-mm-yy hh:ii is there any solution to do that.
the column type is VARCHAR

I have already tried that code :

Update all the columns that hold a date as a string to a date column

`` UPDATE metric SET `dateColumn` = str_to_date(`dateColumn`,'%d-%m-%Y'); ``

Alter table

`` ALTER TABLE metric MODIFY `dateColumn` DATETIME; ``

I expect to change all date format from the range that has yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii to dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii

Comment: Can you add a complete table code with data?  normally it will not work as like you are trying  because of its varchar data type not date formatted date

Comment: Store all datetimes using a standard format (e.g. yyyy-mm-DS h:i:s). If seconds are unknown, store 00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column's data type is `VARCHAR`, so before you reformat it you must convert it to datatype `DATETIME` with [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) by checking its current format and then apply the new format to all the rows with [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
update metric
set dateColumn = date_format(
  str_to_date(
    dateColumn, 
    case
      when dateColumn like '__-__-____ __:__' then '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i'
      when dateColumn like '____-__-__ __:__' then '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'
    end
  ),
  '%d-%m-%y %H:%i'
)
where dateColumn like '__-__-____ __:__' or dateColumn like '____-__-__ __:__'
```

The `WHERE` clause is needed just in case there are other formats too.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oRoE6RJXkjx3FysuvzufCS/0).

Answer (score 0):

Apply different parsing formats based on the format:

```
UPDATE metric SET
dateColumn = str_to_date(dateColumn,
  case
    when dateColumn like '__-%'
      then '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i'
    else '%y-%m-%d %H:%i'
  end)
```

I’m not sure about the exact format to use for parsing because it wasn’t that clear to me from the question, but this should be close if not correct.